# how does one compare the date part of a nullable datetime in a linq / lambda query?

Tags: c#, linq, datetime

I have something like the following:

```
new ObservableCollection<SomeData>(SomeDataCollection.Where(a => a.AGD_Category.Equals((int)AGD_CategoryEnum.Med) && ((a.AGG_DateStart.Date <= SelectedUntill) && (a.AGG_DateEnd.Value.Date >= SelectedFrom))));
```

now my a.AGG_DateEnd is a nullable datetime and whenever there is a null value in the list I get an exception   because of the "a.AGG_DateEnd.Value.Date" part.

But the thing is, the a.AGG_DateEnd also contains hours and minutes, but I do not want this causes my comparison to give unreliable results.

What can I do to improve?

Thank you,

Comment: you could just add a null check inside your .Where(...). Nullable Types have a property called 'HasValue' which does exactly that. So a.AGG_DateEnd.HasValue should do the trick.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

A quick hack is:

```
a.AGG_DateEnd.GetValueOrDefault().Date >= SelectedFrom
```

This is OK because the `default(DateTime)` (which equals its own `.Date`) is not greater than any (other) `DateTime` value.

Otherwise the usual thing to do is:

```
a.AGG_DateEnd.HasValue && a.AGG_DateEnd.Value.Date >= SelectedFrom
```

where the double `&` ensures short-cut evaluation.

---

Addition after comments:

If you want the opposite answer in the case where it is `null`, it is:

```
(a.AGG_DateEnd ?? DateTime.MaxValue).Date >= SelectedFrom
```

respectively:

```
!a.AGG_DateEnd.HasValue || a.AGG_DateEnd.Value.Date >= SelectedFrom
```

---

**Later edit:** Since C# 6.0 (July 2015), you can use the `?.` operator instead. So use the shorter code:

```
a.AGG_DateEnd?.Date >= SelectedFrom
```

which will (formally, at least) compare two nullable values of type `DateTime?`. When either operand is "null" (i.e. `.HasValue` gives `false`), such a comparison gives `false`.

If you want the opposite bool result in case of null, that is:

```
!(a.AGG_DateEnd?.Date < SelectedFrom)
```

Observe how `x >= y` is different from `!(x < y)` when we use these *lifted* operators that operate on `Nullable<>` values. Any lifted operator (like `>=` or `<`) will return `false` immediately if one of `x` and `y` is null; only if both `x` and `y` are non-null, will they be *unwrapped* and the contents compared with the non-lifted operator whose return value will be used.

Comment: I see... thanks for your answer, I will accept it.... 
Whenever a AGG_DateEnd is null, it will not end up in the resultset. Is it possible to use a fictional date if AGG_DateEnd is null like 31/12/4711? I mean to replace AGG_DateEnd...

Comment: ... Never mind, just need to do this : a.AGG_DateEnd.GetValueOrDefault(new DateTime(4711, 12, 31)) >= SelectedFrom    !!  THANK YOU

Comment: @user1841243 I extended that answer for that. Note that you can use `(x ?? y)` instead of `x.GetValueOrDefault(y)` if you prefer.